# How i can read JSON code selected by BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, arrays, json, web-scraping

I need to read this JSON code, to be able to filter and find the information I need, but I'm not getting it

```
from cgitb import html
from traceback import print_list
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://blaze.com/pt/games/double'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
bsobj = BeautifulSoup(result.content.decode(), "html.parser")

print(bsobj.body.script)
```

I made the selection of the part I need with BeautifulSoup, but I'm not able to read it with json.loads it's giving me an error, can someone help me?

Output of this error

```
<script>!function(e){function a(a){for(var c,d,n=a[0],b=a[1],o=a[2],u=0,l=[];u<n.length;u++)d=n[u],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t,d)&&t[d]&&l.push(t[d][0]),t[d]=0;for(c in b)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(b,c)&&(e[c]=b[c]);for(i&&i(a);l.length;)l.shift()();return r.push.apply(r,o||[]),f()}function f(){for(var e,a=0;a<r.length;a++){for(var f=r[a],c=!0,d=1;d<f.length;d++){var b=f[d];0!==t[b]&&(c=!1)}c&&(r.splice(a--,1),e=n(n.s=f[0]))}return e}var c={},d={23:0},t={23:0},r=[];function n(a){if(c[a])return c[a].exports;var f=c[a]={i:a,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[a].call(f.exports,f,f.exports,n),f.l=!0,f.exports}n.e=function(e){var a=[];d[e]?a.push(d[e]):0!==d[e]&&{3:1,4:1,9:1,10:1,11:1,12:1,14:1,15:1,17:1,18:1,19:1,20:1,27:1,28:1,29:1,30:1,31:1,32:1,33:1,34:1,35:1,36:1,37:1,38:1,39:1,40:1,41:1,42:1,43:1,44:1,45:1,46:1,48:1,49:1,50:1,51:1,52:1,53:1,54:1,55:1,56:1,57:1,58:1,59:1,60:1,61:1,62:1,63:1,64:1,65:1,66:1,67:1,68:1,69:1,70:1,71:1,72:1,73:1,74:1,75:1,76:1,77:1,78:1,79:1,80:1,81:1,82:1,83:1,84:1,85:1,87:1,88:1,89:1,90:1,91:1,92:1,93:1,94:1,95:1,96:1,97:1,98:1,99:1}[e]&&a.push(d[e]=new Promise((function(a,f){for(var c="static/css/"+({}[e]||e)+"."+{0:"31d6cfe0",1:"31d6cfe0",2:"31d6cfe0",3:"9c52530f",4:"91a7d4cf",5:"31d6cfe0",6:"31d6cfe0",7:"31d6cfe0",8:"31d6cfe0",9:"aeefc8c2",10:"18c8bda9",11:"c44627be",12:"7e7e1be9",13:"31d6cfe0",14:"3360e51e",15:"e452749c",16:"31d6cfe0",17:"e71cfd8e",18:"e92d14a9",19:"4194bf36",20:"5c5ed82a",21:"31d6cfe0",25:"31d6cfe0",26:"31d6cfe0",27:"1e101221",28:"6e9473f3",29:"990fe71d",30:"7fba0997",31:"82ee7eed",32:"267af2fa",33:"73e561f1",34:"02bedb5a",35:"4475aee1",36:"d841d209",37:"4c29dec8",38:"2c0c1937",39:"9c6caf91",40:"3e92d0da",41:"04f79b72",42:"9194a19e",43:"a7efabcc",44:"af88a9a1",45:"d6a1283f",46:"04f79b72",47:"31d6cfe0",48:"72593bf9",49:"6fad93bb",50:"5a46aa87",51:"b7326aaf",52:"4f7b2628",53:"547b683e",54:"f8e1e4cc",55:"d27c58b4",56:"812684c2",57:"fbeea41f",58:"736c174e",59:"4ff795c7",60:"bf5d708a",61:"d1167ff1",62:"d1167ff1",63:"c9f5a51d",64:"428335fd",65:"428335fd",66:"3adc3736",67:"3adc3736",68:"3adc3736",69:"3adc3736",70:"3adc3736",71:"3adc3736",72:"db32bba2",73:"0b37414a",74:"0b82a96a",75:"b3f9c997",76:"f9277481",77:"4ff795c7",78:"67277312",79:"428335fd",80:"d05d2a8c",81:"fd57c581",82:"e92d14a9",83:"e92d14a9",84:"fdd8ba69",85:"489bfbbb",86:"31d6cfe0",87:"f805e11f",88:"489bfbbb",89:"489bfbbb",90:"afd7172b",91:"1103b4ec",92:"04369886",93:"0da63587",94:"af0493d1",95:"b4add976",96:"fd57c581",97:"d3a2ea4a",98:"afd7172b",99:"d12a93b8",100:"31d6cfe0",101:"31d6cfe0",102:"31d6cfe0",103:"31d6cfe0",104:"31d6cfe0",105:"31d6cfe0",106:"31d6cfe0",107:"31d6cfe0",108:"31d6cfe0",109:"31d6cfe0",110:"31d6cfe0",111:"31d6cfe0",112:"31d6cfe0",113:"31d6cfe0",114:"31d6cfe0",115:"31d6cfe0",116:"31d6cfe0",117:"31d6cfe0",118:"31d6cfe0",119:"31d6cfe0"}[e]+".chunk.css",t=n.p+c,r=document.getElementsByTagName("link"),b=0;b<r.length;b++){var o=(i=r[b]).getAttribute("data-href")||i.getAttribute("href");if("stylesheet"===i.rel&&(o===c||o===t))return a()}var u=document.getElementsByTagName("style");for(b=0;b<u.length;b++){var i;if((o=(i=u[b]).getAttribute("data-href"))===c||o===t)return a()}var l=document.createElement("link");l.rel="stylesheet",l.type="text/css",l.onload=a,l.onerror=function(a){var c=a&&a.target&&a.target.src||t,r=new Error("Loading CSS chunk "+e+" failed.\n("+c+")");r.code="CSS_CHUNK_LOAD_FAILED",r.request=c,delete d[e],l.parentNode.removeChild(l),f(r)},l.href=t,document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(l)})).then((function(){d[e]=0})));var f=t[e];if(0!==f)if(f)a.push(f[2]);else{var c=new Promise((function(a,c){f=t[e]=[a,c]}));a.push(f[2]=c);var r,b=document.createElement("script");b.charset="utf-8",b.timeout=120,n.nc&&b.setAttribute("nonce",n.nc),b.src=function(e){return n.p+"static/js/"+({}[e]||e)+"."+{0:"5e94ce45",1:"13372496",2:"ba421446",3:"231fbb4a",4:"f06722b3",5:"7af54a0f",6:"6f155ba5",7:"f39720e2",8:"f8fbc983",9:"56707766",10:"64100866",11:"8843f4e7",12:"7d0d65b1",13:"e7759828",14:"2cbeb473",15:"80fcbac6",16:"8886cd62",17:"24db4be7",18:"06b3ac3c",19:"2091f287",20:"c1d679aa",21:"1aba33f7",25:"81688a01",26:"c10af8b4",27:"161968ff",28:"0381efe4",29:"8f1e1f89",30:"41bd658f",31:"91238780",32:"9f3387d7",33:"a095f250",34:"cd2d6a35",35:"3e3d4d6b",36:"56b285d3",37:"23936eea",38:"2bec5c03",39:"70a2a999",40:"24193c1a",41:"d5bd33c4",42:"c4aeb5df",43:"95b3ae94",44:"7ba387d5",45:"2017ef37",46:"b1a78052",47:"1aa064e8",48:"49072d11",49:"8ba68ec5",50:"d27ffc69",51:"15daab78",52:"f9502843",53:"7b4eb914",54:"6f0eddf2",55:"22b0f45e",56:"8ce2e11b",57:"966d71e8",58:"e2a3ff6a",59:"0951783a",60:"3b2d7021",61:"989f4de3",62:"0dc9ad9b",63:"01cabef2",64:"f19d3bf7",65:"a54b7293",66:"6465613d",67:"6d8b8028",68:"6cced9fc",69:"1e8fc878",70:"4c86443a",71:"fa7a918b",72:"4711c39c",73:"c04d09ba",74:"0e4918c5",75:"60f88339",76:"d75506dc",77:"0462b837",78:"2e2db900",79:"52debae9",80:"a8ee5340",81:"d4d70d20",82:"41a5cc6c",83:"8842a629",84:"ffa7ca98",85:"9021d99b",86:"13d1822d",87:"b5b63f7a",88:"ed4ad906",89:"525fd66f",90:"756c511f",91:"214e0785",92:"2fdcd90f",93:"53e106ae",94:"d752a45e",95:"ba10a333",96:"cf67904f",97:"ceb878bc",98:"851ee334",99:"490109d8",100:"12a3391a",101:"cc271b6b",102:"17cc6122",103:"2a8b4095",104:"6cc18200",105:"fba14cae",106:"4816408b",107:"0649c315",108:"85de1979",109:"e46552bd",110:"d153308b",111:"8ed06c07",112:"8b3ef225",113:"d7fa2dde",114:"a7767e71",115:"523c5fb9",116:"6dcaf3d8",117:"fdabc2d8",118:"de7122e4",119:"14b875d1"}[e]+".chunk.js"}(e);var o=new Error;r=function(a){b.onerror=b.onload=null,clearTimeout(u);var f=t[e];if(0!==f){if(f){var c=a&&("load"===a.type?"missing":a.type),d=a&&a.target&&a.target.src;o.message="Loading chunk "+e+" failed.\n("+c+": "+d+")",o.name="ChunkLoadError",o.type=c,o.request=d,f[1](o)}t[e]=void 0}};var u=setTimeout((function(){r({type:"timeout",target:b})}),12e4);b.onerror=b.onload=r,document.head.appendChild(b)}return Promise.all(a)},n.m=e,n.c=c,n.d=function(e,a,f){n.o(e,a)||Object.defineProperty(e,a,{enumerable:!0,get:f})},n.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},n.t=function(e,a){if(1&a&&(e=n(e)),8&a)return e;if(4&a&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var f=Object.create(null);if(n.r(f),Object.defineProperty(f,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&a&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var c in e)n.d(f,c,function(a){return e[a]}.bind(null,c));return f},n.n=function(e){var a=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return n.d(a,"a",a),a},n.o=function(e,a){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,a)},n.p="/",n.oe=function(e){throw console.error(e),e};var b=this["webpackJsonpblaze-client"]=this["webpackJsonpblaze-client"]||[],o=b.push.bind(b);b.push=a,b=b.slice();for(var u=0;u<b.length;u++)a(b[u]);var i=o;f()}([])</script>
´´´
```

Comment: That's not JSON, that's a bunch of JavaScript enclosed in script tags. You might need to use something more powerful (e.g. Selenium) for this.

Comment: Do you know of any videos or materials that can help me? The codes using Selenium that I'm doing, I'm not getting a response, the spider is always caught by the site's system and it blocks it

Comment: Not off the top of my head. I'd look up Selenium's docs or a tutorial. (I'm not a huge Selenium user.)